# Coloring polygons in a shapefile

Tags: ruby, gis, polygon, shapefile, georuby

I've got an [ESRI Shapefile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) containing polygons of administrative regions, and data corresponding to those regions.  I'd like to produce images of those shapefiles colored according to the data, like [this](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles):

[image]

Here's an answer about doing this in [ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586389/coloring-a-shapefile-map-in-asp-net), and the above image was generated with R; unfortunately I'm not familiar with either language.  Is there a straightforward way to do this in Ruby, eg. [GeoRuby](http://georuby.rubyforge.org/)?  Ideas for easily accomplishing this in eg. Java, C or (shudder) PHP will also be entertained.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with shapefile manipulation, but you might want to have a look into the [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/) ruby bindings. They should allow you to access the data from the shapefile file, which you can then draw using either gnuplot or (and that would be my pick) [the RMagick/GraphicsMagick library](https://web.archive.org/web/20161001210202/http://rmagick.rubyforge.org:80/portfolio3.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Ruby wrapper for Gnuplot](https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot), and some of [these examples](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_4.4/fillcrvs.html) for Gnuplot on how to draw filled shapes.

Comment: Is there a sensible way to pass in ESRI Shapefiles?  They're (cough) a bit more complex than your average CSV.

Comment: There's the http://ruby-shapelib.sourceforge.net/ project, but it doesn't seem to be actively maintained.